# Migration from codeigniter to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter

What is the best `mvc framework` for `php` and how to get started with it?

Comment: welcome to the laravel gang :), the internet is full with tutorials, you just need basic knowledge of php

Comment: knowledge of Basic PHP, Object Oriented PHP and Composer dependency manager is a must to start Laravel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel is a PHP based MVC framework. The architecture is based on the MVC programming paradigm, but the building blocks are PHP functions. To learn Laravel without learning PHP first is a risky endeavor. You may not be very productive with it. You might not be able to create abstract functionality that is not included in the framework.

So, Before starting Laravel You must have—

1. The basic knowledge of HTML, CSS and Javascript
2. Good knowledge of Core and Advance PHP-
3. Core PHP includes the basic PHP and its functions.
4. Advance PHP includes the OOPS concept and libraries, packages.
5. A good vision of Composer is essential as you will use composer for accessing the Laravel’s functionalities and downloading packages.
6. Knowledge of MVC Structure, You must know the flow of things, How the things go in MVC frameworks, How everything interacts and all. It can help you a lot during learning.
7. And Last one is the Knowledge of Database. (well Laravel makes it quite easy to handle with database queries as The Eloquent ORM provides a beautiful, simple ActiveRecord implementation for working with your database.)
   This must be required before start learning Laravel else You will get frustrate in the mid of your learning and takes a lot of time in it. It would be great to start with CI first to get Laravel and its concept quite easily.

For more tutorials based on Laravel must visit this site - [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com)

Refernce : http://www.phpwala.in/laravel/things-must-know-before-starting-laravel/2018/03